# C# Program to update files in local disk over a network mapped drive

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2010, client-server, updates

I am starting to work in a program to browse and open certain files, that are well organized in my hard drive, this files are technical information that i can review if a need to configure a machine, etc, this program needs the ability to update the files over a mapped drive of my company network.

I need help about how to structure the updating system, im not asking for code but if you point me in the right direction that will be great, i am having a hard time trying to define how to do the updating process, what logic use when the program looks for updates and how to define what it needs to be updated and then copy only those files, do i need to put a database in the mapped drive?, maybe in local machine as well.

Only a few people will be doing the update on the server, with  another program with only this purpose, then clients will update locally.

Comment: What does the updating process do?

Comment: update local files from an UNC path, if new files were added to server then the client can check for new updates and start updating process if any was found, hope this is clear enough. Files = Pds, xls, doc, etc.

Comment: Is your app suppose to do something like files synchronization between you local disk and network drive ?

Comment: yes, should be a multiclient app, the will be installed in multiple machines so every user can have updated files.

Comment: Zilog, files sync never came to my mind and maybe that is what i need,i found microsoft sync framework, so intead of creating a whole new updating system, maybe i should use that, Ill keep searching info about MSF to find out if meets my expectations.